# jQuery Datatables element placement

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

I'm working on a page that's using jQuery Datatables and I'm trying to figure out how to place an element within the markup.

Here's the page:

[image]

I want the "Click here to download full report" link to align on the right on the same line as the "Funding Summary" title.

Here's the code I used to add the title:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   var FStable = $('#tblFundingSummary').dataTable(
       {
           "scrollY": "300px",
           "scrollCollapse": true,
           "paging": false,

           dom: '<"toolbar">rti<"floatRight"B><"clear">',

           buttons: {
               buttons: [
                   { extend: 'excel', text: 'Export to Excel', exportOption: { page: 'current' }, footer: true }
               ]
           }

       });

   $("#tblFundingSummary_wrapper div.toolbar").html('<h2>Funding Summary</h2><div style="text-align: right; float:right;"><a id="aExport" title="Click here to download full report" OnServerClick="ExportFundingSummaryToExcel"  runat="server">Click here to download full report</a></div>');
```

Comment: Add a class to the button n customize with css?

Comment: `dom: '<"toolbar"><"floatRight"B>rti<"clear">',`
? -> https://jsfiddle.net/zm825k01/5/

Comment: Thanks davidkonrad, but this isn't the Excel button functionality for datatables, this is making a server side call to fire off a completely different stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

Since you are adding the header and button via code you can mark `<h2>` as `display:inline-block` or `float:left` or any other css setting that will fulfill your requirement

```
$("#tblFundingSummary_wrapper div.toolbar")
     .html('<h2 style="display: inline-block;">Funding Summary</h2><div style="text-align: right; float:right;"><a id="aExport" title="Click here to download full report" OnServerClick="ExportFundingSummaryToExcel"  runat="server">Click here to download full report</a></div>');
```

Comment: That puts it right next to the title, and aligned slightly above it.

Comment: @TrevorGoodchild I won't be putting any wildshots on what kind of css styles already apply on those items, what kind of margins do you have on that header node etc. If you can manipulate the structure you can use the following `$("#tblFundingSummary_wrapper div.toolbar")
     .html('<h2>Funding Summary<small style="text-align: right; float:right;"><a id="aExport" title="Click here to download full report" OnServerClick="ExportFundingSummaryToExcel"  runat="server">Click here to download full report</a></small ></h2>');`

Comment: Right, forgot that I was padding the top by 15px.  That aligns it with the title, still can't get it to align to the right though.

Comment: Okay, so I thought div.toolbar extended across the width of the whole grid, it does not.